# Получить значения до тега <br> в переменные

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, dom

Есть html-код вида:

```
"Имя: ФИО<br>
Телефон: ---<br>
E-mail: ---<br>
Cамовывоз<br>
Способ оплаты: Наличными<br>
Дополнительно: <br>это тест<br><br>
<table border=1 cellpadding=5> - и потом таблица"
```

Мне нужно получить из всего текста лишь "Самовывоз" (т.е. способ доставки) и "Наличными" (т.е. конкретный способ оплаты).
Начал делать через DOMDocument, но не получается - лишь могу достать значения внутри парных тегов.
Регуляркой не могу достать вовсе, хотя этот вариант применим, как думаю.
Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: `explode('<br>', $txt)[3]` ?

Comment: Идеально. Можете оформить как ответ, я его как правильный отмечу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку в вашем тексте разделитель строк в целом очевиден, то можно просто разбить текст по нему с помощью `explode()`, либо как вариант `preg_split` (если вдруг могут быть как `<br>` так и `<br/>` тэги `/<br\/?>/g`).

После разбиения третий элемент получившегося массива будет содержать искомую строку. Так что тут варианты

```
$data = explode('<br>', $txt);
$shipping  = $data[3];
```

Либо

```
list(,,,$shipping) = explode('<br>', $txt);
```

Либо для пхп 7

```
[,,,$shipping] = explode('<br>', $txt);
```

Однако, надо быть уверенным, что строки (ФИО, телефон) выше не содержат  `<br>`, то есть вводимые данные должны экранироваться, и перед формированием данного html-кода нет вызова `nl2br()`, к примеру.